# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load SystemTransform from loader

Tags: android, vlc, aar

When I import the vlc .aar file in my project, there is no problem with the compilation, but the error is

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load SystemTransform from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/xx.com.hvideo-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/xx.com.hvideo-1/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
```

Is my gradle misconfigured, but I have no problems with other projects.Here is my gradle code：

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xx.com.xx"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets {

    main {

        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']

    }

}

}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/MCRSDK.jar')
    compile files('libs/vmsnetsdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/PlayerSDK.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.6.2.jar')
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile project(':mediapicker')
    compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
    compile project(':pulltorefresh')
    compile(name:'libvlc-3.0.0-2.1.0',ext:'aar')
}
```

Here is my project structure：

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know how to fix it! The reason is that the arm packet corresponds to this different processor. Different arm packets inside the .so file must be consistent. I am in the lib directory to create a new armeabi-v7a directory, the armeabi file below the. So file copied into, and then solve the problem!